# Finding number of lines of a data file using command line

Tags: command-line, fortran, wc

There is a conventional way to read each line one by one and check `iostat` hits nonzero or negative value at every reading. However, I would like to call `system(command)` routine and
use `wc -l` command to count the number of and then want to allocate the dimension of the array where I want to put the data. For the example, I am printing the number of lines in both ways:

```fortran
Program Test_reading_lines
    integer:: count,ios, whatever
    character(LEN=100):: command

    Print*,'Reading number of lines in a standard way'

    count=0
    open (10, file='DATA_FILE')
     Do
           read (10,*,iostat=ios) whatever
           if (ios/=0) exit     
         count=count+1
      End Do
    close(10)


    Print*,'Number of lines =', count



    Print*,'Reading number of lines using shell command'

    command='cat DATA_FILE | wc -l'
    call system(command)

    Print*,'Number of lines =','< ? >' 


    End Program Test_reading_lines
```

Unfortunately, in the latter case, can I assign a variable like `count` as in the standard case? That is, I want to print a variable instead of `'< ? >'` in the last print command.

Comment: Use the `fortran` tag, there is nothing specific fortran90 in your question. Even if it were specific, use both tags. It is quite likely you did not get any attention up to now because of that.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF, I'll keep this in mind while tagging next time.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in a straightforward way. You could redirect the output of the command to a file, then open it and read it http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.fortran/how-to-get-the-output-of-call-system-in-a-v/216294

Or use some even more sophisticated features of the Unix  functions and call its C API (see the first answer in that thread).

The [EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html) also does not have any feature to read the output of the command directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the Unix command `$ wc -l`, you could call the Fortran subroutine `execute_command_line` which is common to many Fortran compilers, `gfortran` included.

Here is a working example which computes the number of lines, `nlines`, of a file called `style.gnuplot` and then uses `nlines` to append some rows to `style.gnuplot` by overwriting the last one.

```fortran
PROGRAM numLines

    IMPLICIT NONE
    integer, parameter :: n = 100
    integer :: i, nLines
    real, parameter :: x0 = -3.14, xEnd = 3.14
    real :: dx
    real, dimension (:), allocatable :: x, fun

    allocate(x(0:n)) ! Allocate the x array
    allocate(fun(0:n)) ! Allocate the fun array

    dx = abs(xEnd-x0)/n
    x(0:n) = [(x0+i*dx, i = 0,n)] ! Create the x array
    fun(0:n) = [(sin(x0+i*dx), i = 0,n)] ! Create the fun array

    open(unit=1,file="plotFunction.dat")
        DO i=0,size(x)-1
            write(1,*) x(i), ' ', fun(i) ! Save the function to a file to plot
        END DO
    close(unit=1)

    deallocate(x) ! Deallocate the x array
    deallocate(fun) ! Deallocate the fun array

    open(unit=7, file="style.gnuplot")
        write(7,*) "set title 'y = sin(x)' font 'times, 24'"
        write(7,*) "set tics font 'times, 20'"
        write(7,*) "set key font 'times,20'"
        write(7,*) "set grid"
        write(7,*) "set key spacing 1.5"
        write(7,*) "plot '<cat' u 1:2 w l lw 2  linecolor rgb 'orange' notitle "
    close(unit=7)

    CALL execute_command_line("wc -l style.gnuplot | cut -f1 -d' ' > nlines.file") ! COunt the lines

    open(unit=1,file='nlines.file')
        read(1,*) nlines ! Here the number of lines is saved to a variable
    close(unit=1)

    CALL execute_command_line("rm nlines.file") ! Remove nlines.file

    CALL execute_command_line("cat plotFunction.dat | gnuplot -p style.gnuplot") ! Show the plot within the executable

    open(unit=7,file="style.gnuplot")
        DO i = 1,nLines-1 
            read(7,*) ! Read the file untile the penultimate row,
        END DO        ! then append the other rows
        write(7,*) "set object rectangle at -3.14,0 size char 1, char 1", & 
                                                                    " fillcolor rgb 'blue' fillstyle solid border lt 2 lw 1.5"
        write(7,*) "set object rectangle at 0,0 size char 1, char 1", & 
                                                                    " fillcolor rgb 'blue' fillstyle solid border lt 2 lw 1.5"
        write(7,*) "set object rectangle at 3.14,0 size char 1, char 1", & 
                                                                    " fillcolor rgb 'blue' fillstyle solid border lt 2 lw 1.5"
        write(7,*) "plot 'plotFunction.dat' u 1:2 w l lw 2  linecolor rgb 'orange' notitle"
    close(unit=7)

    CALL execute_command_line("gnuplot -p 'style.gnuplot'") ! Load again style.gnulot with the appended lines

END PROGRAM numLines
```

My code might not be elegant, but it seems to work!

Comment: Yes, this should work. Unfortunately it is the indirect way, when you have to save the output to an external file and the read it from Fortran.

Comment: I see. What is the main disadvantage in using this solution? Does it increase the CPU time a lot?

Comment: Well, any disk input and output takes quite some time, of course. It depends whether you care about that in your application.